# React Variable value is not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

i'm trying to do something in react and i got stuck .. i don't know why this is happening, i can't explain myself.

```
let content = null;
storage.ref().child(snapshot.val().content).getDownloadURL().then(url => content = url ); // setting value

console.log('content', content); // returns initial value, in my case, null. why?
```

Line 19

https://pastebin.com/UkJyJihB

Thanks!

Comment: Because `content` is `null` ?

Comment: no, if i define the variable like `let content = 'something';` , the console log will echo 'something', but if i console log the `url` from the `then` function, the echo will be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your action is asynchronous. It means that 'then' function fires only when getDownloadURL() is finished. But console.log fires immidiately, when the content is null yet. So if you want to do something with content, you should do it inside 'then' callback:

```
let content = null;
storage.ref().child(snapshot.val().content).getDownloadURL()
.then(url => {
   content = url; 
   console.log('content', content);
} );
```

Comment: Yeap, now it's working. But another little question, how I can make to be in real time? For example if I change some value from firebase console, I want in my project to be displayed without to refresh  the page. Thanks for  your time, Alexander!

Comment: For real-time actions, you should use websockets instead of a http requests. Here is popular library for it with demos and docs https://socket.io